# Javascript-Difference between RegExp Instance and RegExp Object

Tags: javascript, regex

I have gone through Mozilla Developer Network Website for Deprecated and obsolete features
in Javascript And found this line

The following are now properties of **RegExp instances,** no longer of the **RegExp object**:

> - global
> - ignoreCase
> - lastIndex
> - multiline
> - source

I'm confused,Please anyone tell the  difference between instance and Object in Javascript clearly.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#RegExp_Methods

Comment: Please edit your question to include the line you are talking about. Right now it says `Blockquote`.

Comment: @Daniël Knippers is it okay now? please answer my question. Thank you

Comment: I'm not an expert here, but the RegExp object = `RegExp`, whereas an instance would be (for example:) `var regex = new RegExp('\w+', 'g')`. The latter will now have the properties you listed. For example, because I passed 'g' it will have `.global == true`. But it is unclear to me how those properties would have made sense on an uninstantiated Object before. So let's wait for a more insightful answer.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [ECMAScript 6th Edition Draft](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-properties-of-regexp-instances):

> Prior to the 6th Edition [of ECMAScript], RegExp instances were
>   specified as having the own data properties source, global,
>   ignoreCase, and multiline. Those properties are now specified as
>   accessor properties of RegExp.prototype.

This change affects the return value of the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method, which now returns `true` or `false` for the enlisted properties, when invoked on the `RegExp.prototype` object or `RegExp` instances, respectively.

Comment: No, that's not what the MDN text refers to.

Comment: It's poorly worded, but I'm reasonably certain it does refer to this change. Note that MDN is a public wiki – anyone can contribute and therefore its content quality varies.

Comment: No, there really was (in the *very* old days) a time where the `RegExp` constructor itself held properties such as the last match, the input, and captured groups - of the last regex execution in the program. Those are referenced by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#RegExp_Properties - and I'm pretty sure that the `.global` etc had the same bug.

Comment: You can see them in action on this [MSDN docs page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/9dthzd08(v=vs.94).aspx). "*The global RegExp object should not be confused with the Regular Expression object. Even though they sound like the same thing, they are separate and distinct. The properties of the global RegExp object contain continually updated information about each match as it occurs, while the properties of the Regular Expression object contain only information about the matches that occur with that instance of the Regular Expression.*" However I can't find docs on those flag properties.

Comment: If you're talking about the likes of `RegExp.lastMatch`, then yes, although these weren't really a bug, but rather a non-standard language extension (like `__proto__`). However, the `global`, `ignoreCase`, `multiline` and `source` flags have never been `RegExp` object properties (not even in ye olde days), so my original answer stands.

Comment: Hm, if it is a misinformation, [it lasted long](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp$revision/16377). While I may not be entirely correct, it's out of question that [this statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features$revision/53737) referred to ES6.

Comment: Intriguing. Notice that the first revision of that text says *deprecated as of JavaScript 1.5*. Firefox never supported anything below JavaScript 1.5, so this puts us in the murky waters of JS as supported by Netscape Navigator. I guess I'll download it to test your hypothesis.

Comment: Hm, I cannot find any evidence that `.globa`, `.ignoreCase`, `.multiline` or `.source` had been `RegExp` object properties. There's no [Mozilla Bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?longdesc=RegExp&component=JavaScript%20Engine&longdesc_type=allwordssubstr), and even the oldest [docs of NN](http://web.archive.org/web/20040811152046/http://developer.netscape.com/docs/manuals/js/core/jsref/regexp.htm) and [IE](http://web.archive.org/web/20050910102123/http://www.msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/script56/html/js56jsobjregexp.asp) say "*property of an individual regular expression object*"

Comment: I tested [NN 4.04](http://www.oldapps.com/netscape.php?old_netscape=7672) ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UQmvo.png)) and was unable to reproduce the behavior described in [the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#RegExp_Properties). The `multiline` property is present, though.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. Not sure how enumerability worked back then, can you try to explicitly access them?

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work very well with the built-in objects: [NN 4.04](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MlIe4.png), [IE5](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zdFeF.png). I'd like to test IE3 next.